# excel set cell style C#

Tags: c#, excel

Most of the styles set for excel through C# code are done for ranges. In my case I don't want to set style to a range but to a single cell. How can I achieve this?

Like this:

```
Excel.Range r;
r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("c4", "e4");
r.Orientation = -90;
```

How to do it for a single cell?

Thanks indeed

Answer (score 1):

Below too is fine. You don't have to repeat "c4" in get_Range to select only one cell.

```
r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("c4");
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use

```
r = xlWorkSheet.get_Range("c4", "c4")
```